# Problema com LEFT JOIN usando Pentaho Kettle

Tags: sql, join, pentaho

Existe um comportamento com relação ao JOIN que não consigo entender.

Tenho duas tabelas nestes formatos

Tabela Doente

```
 ID_Doente Doente 
 1          Pedro
 2          Paulo
 3          Rui
```

Tabela consulta

```
 ID_Consulta  ID_Doente Tipo
 1            2        Não Medica
 2            2        Médica
```

E estou a fazer um left join como este:

```
SELECT *
FROM Consulta
LEFT JOIN Doente
ON Consulta.ID_Doente =Doente.ID_Doente;
```

Eu estava com a ideia que o resultado seria algo como isto

```
ID_Consulta  ID_Doente    Tipo         Doente
 1             2        Não Medica    Paulo
 2             2        Médica        Paulo
```

Mas no entanto estou a ter isto

```
ID_Consulta  ID_Doente    Tipo         Doente
 1             2        Não Medica    Paulo
 2             2        Médica        NULL
```

Alguém sabe a razão?

EDIT: Isto é um exemplo do que está a acontecer, eu estou a realizar isto usando a funcionalidade de merge left join do Pentaho Kettle

EDIT2: Questão foi respondida aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459143/pentaho-kettle-weird-left-join-results

Comment: Que banco de dados você está usando? Não consegui reproduzir [no MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ea54/1) nem [no PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8ea54/1) nem [no SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ea54/1) nem [no SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8ea54/1).

Comment: Pois, talvez esse seja o problema, eu estou a realizar este left join nas tabelas no Pentaho Kettle.

Comment: Não vejo como é possível ter esse tipo de resultset dada a estrutura das tabelas e as queries. Ambos parecem ok. Você tentou rodar a query diretamente no banco de dados para ver o que acontece?

Comment: Não é possivel porque estou a usar o Kettle como intermediario para realizar joins no MongoDB, que se não me engano não suporta joins. Mas de qualquer forma usar MongoDB não deve ser o problema pois o Kettle coloca os dados em tabelas tipo SQL após algumas transformações.

Comment: O que acontece se você fizer um `FULL JOIN` ou `CROSS JOIN`? Acho que não, mas talvez o problema seja em alguma das etapas anteriores de transformação que o Pentaho faz nos seus dados antes de cruzá-los. (não tenho muita experiência com o Pentaho, então desculpe se estiver falando besteira...)

Comment: Estou a testar o full join neste momento, mas duvido que o problema seja nas etapas anteriores, porque por exemplo neste exemplo ele faz join num dos casos com ID 40 mas nos outros por alguma razão não faz http://i.imgur.com/VVqbF2e.png

Comment: Fiz um [breve teste](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9627838) em Sql Server e o resultado é o esperado. Será que é por não estares a dar alias ás tabelas ?

Comment: Pelo menos em MySQL isso funciona bem. Tenta montar um sqlfiddle que reproduza o problema. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e04d/1

Comment: @user3323032 Quero lembrar também que, a não ser que realmente hajam consultas sem paciente, não há razão pra usar `LEFT JOIN`. O `LEFT JOIN` é específico para casos especiais onde você quer listar relação entre tabelas onde nem todos os índices fazem crusamento.

Comment: Parece que a pergunta já foi respondida no SOE ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459143/pentaho-kettle-weird-left-join-results)). O problema foi que o autor da pergunta esqueceu de ordenar os dados antes de fazer um **merge join**.

Answer (score 2):

Testei seu SQL no SQLServer e funcionou normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema deve ser na engine do Pentaho Kettle.

O código a seguir é a mesma coisa, mas tente pra ver se funciona, pois deve ser um problema estrutural no Pentaho.

```
SELECT *
FROM Doente 
RIGHT JOIN Consulta
ON Consulta.ID_Doente =Doente.ID_Doente;
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem ?
Acredito que você possa estar utilizando um join sem adicionar o componente Sort senão podem sair resultados não esperados.

**Veja a o que cita a documentação do kettle.**
[image: Documentação Pentaho]

Sempre que for utilizar um **JOIN** no Pentaho adicione um **Step Sort** com os **IDs** de ligação para que o pentaho consiga classificar os resultados antes de juntar, assim conseguirá classificar sem maiores problemas

[image: Step Join com Sort]

Espero ter ajudado.